# How do I parse a token from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, tokenize

How do i parse tokens from an input string.
For example:

```
char *aString = "Hello world".
```

I want the output to be:

> "Hello" "world"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to want to use `strtok` - [here is a good example.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/String/Truncatestringbydelimiterhowtousestrtok.htm)

Comment: You can use strtok_r() which is thread safe.  You can see them both in the same manpage.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [strtok](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html), part of the standard library.

Answer (score 6):

`strtok` is the easy answer, but what you really need is a lexer that does it properly.  Consider the following:

- are there one or two spaces between "hello" and "world"?
- could that in fact be any amount of whitespace?
- could that include vertical whitespace (\n, \f, \v) or just horizontal (\s, \t, \r)?
- could that include any UNICODE whitespace characters?
- if there were punctuation between the words, ("hello, world"), would the punctuation be a separate token, part of "hello,", or ignored?

As you can see, writing a proper lexer is not straightforward, and `strtok` is not a proper lexer.

Other solutions could be a single character state machine that does precisely what you need, or regex-based solution that makes locating words versus gaps more generalized.  There are many ways.

And of course, all of this depends on what your actual requirements are, and I don't know them, so start with `strtok`.  But it's good to be aware of the various limitations.

Answer (score 3):

For re-entrant versions you can either use
[strtok_s for visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) or [strtok_r for unix](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that strtok is **very** hard to get it right, because:

- It modifies the input
- The delimiter is replaced by a null terminator
- Merges adjacent delimiters, and of course,
- Is not thread safe.

You can read about this [alternative](http://groups.google.co.in/group/comp.lang.c/msg/ae19c3d96edd5297).