# How do I make a token parser in C?

Tags: c, parsing, token

I have seen "config" files(yes, text files) for various console applications that look like the following

```
<token> <value>
```

How would I go about parsing such a thing in C, where < value > could be a string, a letter or even an integer/float/double?

I read this question " [How do I parse a token from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558368/how-do-i-parse-a-token-from-a-string-in-c) " where it is mostly recommended to use strtok, but also that it's not thread-safe, and I am planning on spawning multiple threads(provided I am able to finish my application)

P.S
Here is an example of a token and a value

```
user username123
pass 123456
```

Ah, I forgot the tricky part. I must also be able to parse a token, which has multiple values either separated by a comma.

Comment: On the very thread you linked to there is a comment that says "You can use strtok_r() which is thread safe. You can see them both in the same manpage."

Comment: Define what is `<token>` and `<value>` and it will be easy to provide concrete answers.

Comment: @Arak I have even provided an example.

[at]Vache, I must have missed that, I will take a look, in the meantime I am waiting for more suggestions :)

Comment: Buy the Dragon Book and find out :)  http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886

Comment: Could possibly look into Lex and Yacc (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `fgets()` and `sscanf()` are your friend:

```
int parseTokens(FILE *filePtr, char **tokens, char **values)
{
    int i = 0;

    char line[128];

    while (fgets(line, 127, filePtr)) {
        tokens[i] = malloc(64);
        values[i] = malloc(64);

        sscanf(line, "%s %s", tokens[i], values[i]);

        i++;
    }

    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *tokens[20];
    char *values[20];

    FILE *filePtr = fopen("~/test.txt", "r");

    if (!filePtr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    int count = parseTokens(filePtr, tokens, values);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", tokens[i], values[i]);

        free(tokens[i]);
        free(values[i]);
    }

    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`getc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/getc.html), read characters from an input stream into a per-line buffer. Once you hit a token delimiter, you [`strncpy()` or `strdup()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593798/proper-way-to-copy-c-strings/9593851#9593851) the per-line buffer into a token `char*`. If needed, parse the token again on a within-token delimiter (such as a comma), grabbing a character at a time and storing it in a per-token buffer, until you hit a within-token delimiter. Once you hit a line delimiter, copy the per-line buffer into a value `char*`. If you know the value is an `int`, `float`, etc., use C functions for converting a `char*` into those primitives (e.g., [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtol.html), etc.). If you have multiple token-value pairs, either keep an array of or pointers to token and value `char*` variables. Repeat until EOF (end-of-file).

Comment: I would suggest `strtol` over `atoi` as you cannot judge if it failed or if the number was 0 using `atoi`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("in.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open/read file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* buf = NULL;
    char* key = malloc(64);
    char* val = malloc(64);
    size_t read;
    size_t len = 0;

    if(key == NULL || val == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while((read = getline(&buf, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        sscanf(buf,"%s %s", key, val);
        printf("<%s> <%s>\n", key, val);
    }

    if(buf != NULL)
    {
      free(buf);
    }

    free(key);
    free(val);

    fclose(fp);
```

**in.txt** file:

```
key value
key1 value1
```

**C application** output:

```
<key> <value>
<key1> <value1>
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

how about use `regexp`? if you are in linux, you can just `#include <regexp.h>` to use it. and`man regexp.h`will get how to use it. store them by string. and, it they are number, use `sprintf` to trans them to unmber.